# ImageMagick 'convert -sepia-tone' different on Windows vs. Linux

Tags: windows, linux, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an issue with the 2 images below: the first one is created on Linux, the second one on Windows using the same command, same versions of ImageMagick (6.6.5-0). Tried newer versions of ImageMagick and they all seem to provide different results Windows vs. Linux.

```
convert c.jpg -sepia-tone 80% 1.jpg (on Linux)
convert c.jpg -sepia-tone 80% 2.jpg (on Windows)
```

The results are very different and I cannot figure out why.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
<sub>(source: [selfip.com](http://s45.selfip.com/1.jpg))</sub>
 [image]
<sub>(source: [selfip.com](http://s45.selfip.com/2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had to do

```
convert c.jpg -set colorspace RGB -sepia-tone 80% 1.jpg
```

basically forcing the use of the RGB colorspace and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the release versions of your ImageMagick installations on Linux and Windows are different in more ways than the mere version numbers...

To verify, run this command and compare the outputs *in detail* for the two platforms:

```
convert -version
```

Additionally, you may want to see how the outputs for `convert -list configure` differ. (Note, the format of the outputs this command gives is different anyway on the two platforms -- they are not directly comparable).

Comment: LINUX: Version: ImageMagick 6.6.5-0 2010-10-14 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP


WINDOWS: Version: ImageMagick 6.6.5-0 2010-10-10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

So the versions are exactly the same.

Comment: When i do `convert -list configure` on Linux i get this:
convert -list configure

`lt-convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile configure.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/589.`